# I am making a VB login with SQL and errors with "incorrect syntax near word user" (line bolded). Suggesions?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, authentication, syntax-error

```
Public Class Login
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=AlphaSYS39414;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=********"

Protected Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim account As String = txtusername.Text
        Dim mypassword As String = txtpassword.Text
        Dim sqlCommand As New  _
            SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM User WHERE @User_ID AND @Password", connection)
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_ID", account)
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", mypassword)
        connection.Open()
        **Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()**
        Dim values As New ArrayList()
        If reader.Read Then
            Response.Redirect("https://google.com")
            'Dim returnedUsername As New String(reader("account"))
            'Dim returnedPassword As New String(reader("mypassword"))
        Else
            Response.Redirect("https://yahoo.com")
        End If
    End Using

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: "*User*" is a keyword.  Try it like `"..[User].."` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User` is a reserved keyword as listed on [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) link.

You should change this code

```
SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM User WHERE @User_ID AND @Password", connection)
```

to this

```
SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE @User_ID AND @Password", connection)
```

Answer (score 1):

You sql command seems to be wrong.

Your Sql Query should be like

> `Select * from [Schema].[User] where UserID = @UserID and Password = @Password`

If your table is not in a schema then the query should be

> `Select * from [User] where UserID = @UserID and Password = @Password`